# Is there QGIS plugin to allow 3d visualisation of geological borehole data similar to functionality of Target for ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, modelling

I'm very new to QGIS, I have started using it as my new company is not willing to pay for ArcGIS and Target at this stage so I'm hoping QGIS can substitute not just in the interim but for good.

What I am looking for is a way to load in my borehole database and create 3d visualizations of the data, make cross sections and if possible model seams. Is there any capability within the QGIS world to undertake this kind of work?

Comment: Currently QGIS lacks decent 3D support (its a work in progress). But there are other Open Source tools you can use, even if they're not quite as user friendly. Gene's answer offers an excellent example of one possible solution.

Comment: Dear Gene and All other GIS wizards and contributors, It is interesting reading this post because I'm about to learn how to present geological boreholes and my intention is to investigate if data can be implemented via QGIS or other open source software. With my limited geological background but mainly GIS - I'm looking forward to read your documents :) asap In the meantime, I would like to ask if anyone have migrated to non commercial software regarding geological 3D GIS analysis and thereby what is your experience - do's and don'ts? I'll collaborate if any more specific information is needed

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. If you want to ask a new question, please add it as one.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible but using a Python script in the console 
see [For geologists: 3D geological boreholes](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/For-geologists-3D-geological-boreholes-td5007085.html)

[image: 3D surfaces in QGIS]
[image: boreholes in QGIS]

I presented the scripts in [visualizing 3D data (Z values) or data with z attribute: a solution](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/visualizing-3D-data-Z-values-or-data-with-z-attribute-a-solution-td5005360.html) 
or [QGIS, représentation 3D des couches vectorielles (shapefiles dits 3D ou shapefiles avec attributs z) avec les modules Python Matplotlib ou Visvis à partir de la console Python](http://www.portailsig.org/content/qgis-representation-3d-des-couches-vectorielles-shapefiles-dits-3d-ou-shapefiles-avec-attrib) in French and [QGIS, visualización 3D de capas vectoriales con Python](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/315-qgis-visualizacion-3d-de-capas-vectoriales-con-python)  in Spanish.

More generally I use GRASS GIS to do, see [Automatic 3D geological boreholes representation (automate v.extrude from a table ?): my solution in Python](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Automatic-3D-geological-boreholes-representation-automate-v-extrude-from-a-table-my-solution-in-Pythn-td4978801.html)  and [3D geological volume modeling (raster 3D): is it really possible ?](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/3D-geological-volume-modeling-raster-3D-is-it-really-possible-td4980148.html)

[image: boreholes] boreholes

[image: layer one] layer one

[image: layer 2] layer two

with interpolated surfaces and cross sections:
[image]

or

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this was done in QGIS.

Comment: ??? -> in the references cited about QGIS, I explain how to do it in the QGIS Python console with the Python modules Matplotlib and Visvis

Comment: OK, I have put more effort in, I have translated the other pages.   Thankyou.

Comment: Gene. I have read this a few times and still do not understand where or how you got them.

Comment: With Python, in the French or the Spanish references. With GRASS GIS, in the references an a knowledge of GRASS

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but, for anyone who finds it today, it might be useful to know that you can use the ["Qgis2threejs" plugin to plot boreholes in 3D](http://hydrogeotools.blogspot.se/2015/01/use-qgis2threejs-plugin-to-create-3d.html).

You may also use the ["Midvatten plugin for QGIS"](https://sites.google.com/site/midvattenpluginforqgis/usage/7-extras) to prepare the borehole data for Qgis2threejs plotting.