# TIN Interpolation using vector layer

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, interpolation, tin

I'm writing a plugin in QGIS and I'd like to generate a TIN surface using a vector layer with x,y and z (interpolation attribute).

The idea is to visualize the same result like in the Interpolation plugin but optimize it in my plugin, to facilitate users.

Does such a function exist?

Can I communicate with the Interpolation plugin to generate the result?

Answer (score 1):

see [Is there are QGIS plugin to allow the 3d visualisation of geological borehole data similar to the functionality of Target for ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/is-there-are-qgis-plugin-to-allow-the-3d-visualisation-of-geological-borehole-da) for my solution in Python with the modules Matplotlib and [Visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/)

The Interpolation plugin generates surfaces in ArcInfo ASCII grid format (. asc) but it offers no way to visualize the results in 3D or to process the 3d shapefiles (PointZ,..)

I presented a solution and the scripts in the QGIS-Developer list [visualizing 3D data (Z values) or data with z attribute: a solution](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/visualizing-3D-data-Z-values-or-data-with-z-attribute-a-solution-td5005360.html) 
and, in French, in [QGIS, représentation 3D des couches vectorielles (shapefiles dits 3D ou shapefiles avec attributs z) avec les modules Python Matplotlib ou Visvis à partir de la console Python](http://www.portailsig.org/content/qgis-representation-3d-des-couches-vectorielles-shapefiles-dits-3d-ou-shapefiles-avec-attrib) or in Spanish in [QGIS, visualización 3D de capas vectoriales con Python](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/315-qgis-visualizacion-3d-de-capas-vectoriales-con-python)

**3d visualisation of the points** (Visvis)

[image: points]

**a resulting 3d grid** (here with matplolib function **griddata** but you can use all the interpolation algorithms of Scipy or others modules)

[image: grid]

**The shaded surface** with an elevation colormap (Visvis)

[image: surfaces]

**3d contour lines (Matplotlib)**
[image]

**and for fun ...(Visvis)**

[image]

But build a plugin seems a priori to me very complex and time consuming:

- plot 3 d points is easy.
- but in all other cases, all the scenarios (3D shapefile points, lines or polygons, shapefile with z attribute, interpolation algorithm, ...)  should be considered before.
- You need Python modules that are not present by default in QGIS (like Shapely, Scipy or Visvis)