# How to use Z-Coordinate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, gpx

I was mapping an area in Namibia and also tracked a lot of paths on my way with my Garmin device... so I thought it would be nice to see height differences in my area (esp. interesting in the raining-season... where is the water going to be?)... but then I came to notice, that QGIS does not support the Z-Coordinate when using Shape-Files. I have currently all the data stored as a GPX file, how can I get QGIS (1.8) to recognize the Z-Coordinate?

And yes my device supports the tracking of height, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to have the z value of your waypoints or tracks I usually use GPS babel. In Babel you can load a GPX file and then translate it to a csv file.

[image]

The resulting csv will have each point of the track or each waypoint with the altitude value
this is an example of what you can get.
 [image]

Since it is a csv file, you can load it in to qgis with the "add delimited text layer plugin and then save it as a shp. Hope it helps

Comment: There are 3 ways to your aim :D, nice! I like this one , because I know how to do it :)

Answer (score 11):

Importing the GPX file with `add vector layer`, and selecting `track_points` layer, you get all collected height data in `ele` field. Saving that to shapefile, it is possible to change color according to the `ele` value, or create raster grids etc.

Comment: So That means if I do this I have the Z-Value in the Attribute table? That would be very helpful :)!

Comment: Yes, but only for point layers. I don't know if this can be achieved with line or polygon layers, since the attribute table applies to the whole object, and not the single line points.

Comment: Oh... thats unfortunate! Then I also need to transform my tracks into points? How can I do this?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, use Add vector layer, instead of the GPS tools. "track_points" gives you a point layer built from the trackpoints.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I know to visualize your data in 3 dimensions is using grass' nviz module which should be accessible via  the qgis' grass plugin.

There are some video tutorials on the subject at youtube. For reference I am posting two of those:

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn4nOhequgk
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ib1-mBbWkv4

Comment: Thanks for the links! I will try them! The GRASS ,module was also something I wanted to learn :)

Comment: See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible without NVIZ but using a Python script in the console with Python modules like Matplotlib or Visvis. See my explanations and references in [TIN Interpolation using a vector layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41891/tin-interpolation-using-a-vector-layer/41922#41922) or [Is there are QGIS plugin to allow the 3d visualisation of geological borehole data similar to the functionality of Target for ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/is-there-are-qgis-plugin-to-allow-the-3d-visualisation-of-geological-borehole-da/41719#41719)

[image: 3D QGIS]

Comment: Looks nice, but you have to get the Z-Coordinates from the GPS device into a shapefile first. The GDAL GPX driver gives this advice: 'If the environment variable GPX_ELE_AS_25D is set to YES, the elevation element will be used to set the Z coordinates of waypoints, route points and track points.' I guess this can not be set inside QGIS yet.

Comment: is the resulting shapefile is a 3d shapefile or a shapefile with z attribute, no problem with the method which uses the Python modules Shapely or ogr that allow to treat them.