# How to plot latitude, longitude and elevaltion data in python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, chart

I have latitude and longitude and elevation data in a CSV file and I want to process it in 3d to something like this  [image: something like this]

the data set is kind of like this
[image]

I just want latitude, longitude and elevation

Comment: The graphics come from  [TIN Interpolation using a vector layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41922/2581)