# How to modify the results of a geological dataset from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: qgis, python, arcgis-desktop, r

I have a 3-D point shapefile of a geological fault dataset consisting of x,y, and z columns. I need to create a raster dataset from this point dataset. I have been trying to do this in ArcGIS; however, ArcGIS does not do this correctly as the dataset result is a vertical surface as opposed to a horizontal one. I.e. x, y does not change but z does.

**For example:**

```
x,            y,           z
358749        5997833      270
358749        5997833      280
```

Is there a way I could flip the data (to make x,y horizontal and re-flip back to vertical afterwards) so that it can be interpolated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A 2D GIS like QGIS is not adequate for this sort of thing. You need a 3D GIS like GRASS GIS (free) or ArcGIS with 3D extensions, Python scripting (see for example [Is there are QGIS plugin to allow the 3d visualisation of geological borehole data similar to the functionality of Target for ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/is-there-are-qgis-plugin-to-allow-the-3d-visualisation-of-geological-borehole-da/41719#41719)) or specialized  geological modelling software  like GoCAD.

With the 3D view of GRASS GIS, you can see the problem (geological fault and layers interpolated -> the blue fault surface is a line in 2D, as the yellow, green layers and the red fault from a geological map).

[image]

What you want to do is a simple 90 degrees anticlockwise 3D rotation around the x axis, thus
`y'= z and x'= x

But after, you need to rotate clockwise the resulting raster again and -> a line in QGIS...

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried the following: Z=inverse(y), X=inverse(X) but this did not work. Is this what you mean? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is something I ran into with ArcGIS. If you use 3D analyst you can add a point and extrude it to the lower depth. If you fudge the 2nd point's x or y value by .00001 ArcGIS will see it as a seperate point value for your line and let you actually generate the vertical line. It will have a very slight offset but that .00001 value is negligible in the overall display. You can use a larger decimal (.1, .01, .001, etc.) depending on your map units.

The bottom line that I've experienced (no pun intended) is that generating a perfectly vertical line from coordinates doesn't work as simple as you'd expect in ArcGIS . You can extrude a point to depth, you can edit a line in 3D, or you can offset an x or y value ever so slightly.