# Convert exported ArcGIS .dwg to 3D rendering on AutoCAD 2013?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, 3d, bathymetry

We're working on a bathymetry mapping project of our reservoir, digitized as it was built in 1977. I have a polyline .shp for contours and polygon .shp for area between contours with fields including depth, elevation, area for polygons and length for polylines. Unfortunately, we don't have Spatial or 3D Analyst. For visual presentation and ideally calculate max capacity, I believe the option we're left with is exporting as a .dwg to our Engineer's AutoCAD 2013.

Questions:

- Is this our best option?
- If so, what method should be used to convert to 3D rendering and what attribute data must be present to make it work?
- Also, can z-values be stored in the 'elevation' field?

Comment: An alternative approach may be using an open-source GIS application, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80617/3d-visualisation-with-open-source-gis-software

Comment: Assuming you have Map 3D AutoCAD 2013?

Comment: Did you already use up your 3D analyst trial?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.