# Drill trace line (arrow) from a point (collar) along a given azimuth with a given length

Tags: qgis, point, line

I'm trying to create a diamond drill surface trace line (arrow) from a point (collar) along a given azimuth with a given length from a csv file. This actually stems from a problem of projecting a surface trace from a drill string in Diamond Drilling. I've used trig to define the surface trace on a flat surface but would love to tie this to a DEM in the future!

Comment: What's your GIS software do you use ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: QGIS. My apologies... I thought this was a QGIS specific site. First time here!

Answer (score 1):

IMO in 3D GIS/CAE, to give the buzzwords, you could/should make some own calculations.

The border between [CAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_engineering) and [GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoinformatics) espacially in route desing  and planning is floating. Traditionally GIS, and that is [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) mainly dealing with, comes from mapping and handles 2D/3D related surface objects in different in a geometric fashion (Vectors, Rasters, Triangulates and Routes) and [sometimes real 3D for drilling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/is-there-qgis-plugin-to-allow-3d-visualisation-of-geological-borehole-data-simil) in combination of two spatial scenarions (landscape + drillhole) as you see in GIS.SE context.

IMO if you want to design a real 3D object like a drilling path, you will need some [CGS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_Solid_Geometry) embedded in a spatial data context, combined with 3D routing elements. To do so you could use [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) for example, because deals with data structures and algorithms in both worlds (GIS, CAE).

Especially for your problem you could use:

1. [Point direction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Ray__3.html) context in CGAL called ray
2. Construct a trajectory using the additional z info from surface, the operational depth and the drilling radius to create points for the tunnel hull mesh.
3. Patch the stuff together via a 3D surface mesh algorithm like [Poisson surface reconstruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/index.html) or [a other 3D surface construction algorithm](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html).
4. and display the stuff in a [3D viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSceneGraph).

This could also be done in [python](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/BindingsExamples) (here a 2D trinagulation).

You could also use a toolkit like the [GOCAD mining software](http://www.mirageoscience.com/our-products/software-product/gocad-mining-suite) or [GDM Suite](http://www.brgm.eu/scientific-output/scientific-software/gdm-suite-software-suite-allowing-to-model-represent). For an overview you could snoop in [this list](http://www.3d-geology.de/software/geology_and_mining/#anchor2263825) provided by the Martin Luther University Halle-Wittenberg Germany.