# Borehole data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, borehole

I am currently doing a QGIS project for my apprenticeship and I'm trying to understand the best way to get borehole log data into QGIS so I can visualise it and analyse the data.

Comment: do you mean 3D, or just collar location?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! Can you give more information on your data? Which format does your data currently have?

Comment: I currently have a pdf of a borehole log, i have a borehole log template in excel format. I am wondering what's the best way to be able to overlay this data onto a map of the UK.

Comment: You could possibly find a solution here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41701/is-there-qgis-plugin-to-allow-3d-visualisation-of-geological-borehole-data-simil?rq=1